# How to parse JSON from URL

Tags: json, parsing, go

I requested to a server with a GET and received a JSON format. I'm using Go, and implemented it in Go in beego web framework.

So I have implemented it like this one,

```
func (d *Tom) Get() {
    //passengersFile, err := http.Get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=KLMH2VFJ0LCFNOX5")
    resp, err := http.Get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=KLMH2VF0LCFNOX5")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    //fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp)

    dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    if dec == nil {
        panic("Failed to start decoding JSON data")
    }

    json_map := make(map[string]interface{})

    err = dec.Decode(&json_map)
        for k, v := range json_map {
            if k == "Meta Data"{
                    continue
            }
            fmt.Printf("key[%s] value[%s]\n", k, v)
        }
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

        d.Data["json"] = &json_map
    d.ServeJSON()
}
```

the format of the incoming json is like that ....

```
{
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) prices and volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-05-25 09:31:00",
    "4. Interval": "1min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (1min)": {
    "2018-05-24 14:23:00": {
      "1. open": "98.1432",
      "2. high": "98.1661",
      "3. low": "98.1238",
      "4. close": "98.1500",
      "5. volume": "19106"
    },
    "2018-05-24 14:24:00": {
      "1. open": "98.1500",
      "2. high": "98.1700",
      "3. low": "98.1400",
      "4. close": "98.1650",
      "5. volume": "18279"
    },
    "2018-05-24 14:25:00": {
      "1. open": "98.1650",
      "2. high": "98.2000",
      "3. low": "98.1600",
      "4. close": "98.1900",
      "5. volume": "32085"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to get the "Time Series (1min)" values and iterate on them to get each value of the "Date Time" values, like "1. open", etc. And of course save them on a single json and return it for those who requested it.

Comment: I was just passing by, but your apikey is visible in the code. You may want to hide it.

Comment: If we're being super careful, we may want to delete these comments as the earlier version of the question can be seen

Comment: The safest way now is to delete this question (then only users with > 10k rep can see it), and flag it for a moderator to completely delete it. Then re-post your question without your API key.

Comment: Or, just change your API key. You should do that anyway. Consider your existing API key compromised.

Comment: I have modified the api key, no need to do that ...

Comment: The API key is [still visible in the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50531922/1)

Comment: But to your question: What have you tried? We get questions like this all the time. What searching have you done on Google or SO?

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I'm asking what you have tried, and what problems you had with your approach.

Comment: Well, i have got the Json and iterate it to lose the ‘Meta Data’ and got left with the remaining one, but after that, just got lost and don’t know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual JSON object is quite, unusual - and it does not lend itself to a simple way of turning it into a struct.

For demonstration, I will use [JSONGen](https://github.com/bemasher/JSONGen), a great utility for turning JSON into Go structs.

For the problem at hand, I would probably use a two step approach.

First, parse the whole document (assuming msft.json contains an API response):

```
$ cat msft.json | JSONGen
type _ struct {
    MetaData struct {
        Information   string `json:"1. Information"`
        Interval      string `json:"4. Interval"`
        LastRefreshed string `json:"3. Last Refreshed"`
        OutputSize    string `json:"5. Output Size"`
        Symbol        string `json:"2. Symbol"`
        TimeZone      string `json:"6. Time Zone"`
    } `json:"Meta Data"`
    TimeSeries1min struct {
        _ struct {
            Close  string `json:"4. close"`
            High   string `json:"2. high"`
            ...
```

The problem is  the repeated elements, keyed by datetime, which would probably be better modelled as a list. Anyway, with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) we can parse out a relevant piece and generate another struct:

```
$ cat msft.json | jq '.["Time Series (1min)"]["2018-05-24 15:47:00"]' | JSONGen
type _ struct {
    Close  string `json:"4. close"`
    High   string `json:"2. high"`
    Low    string `json:"3. low"`
    Open   string `json:"1. open"`
    Volume string `json:"5. volume"`
}
```

Now we can combine the two structs into one. Here is a complete program to parse the JSON
input.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type Item struct {
    Close  string `json:"4. close"`
    High   string `json:"2. high"`
    Low    string `json:"3. low"`
    Open   string `json:"1. open"`
    Volume string `json:"5. volume"`
}

type Response struct {
    MetaData struct {
        Information   string `json:"1. Information"`
        Interval      string `json:"4. Interval"`
        LastRefreshed string `json:"3. Last Refreshed"`
        OutputSize    string `json:"5. Output Size"`
        Symbol        string `json:"2. Symbol"`
        TimeZone      string `json:"6. Time Zone"`
    } `json:"Meta Data"`
    TimeSeries1min map[string]Item `json:"Time Series (1min)"`
}
```

We can model the time series as a map of OHLC items. The parsing now gets really simple:

```
func main() {
    resp := Response{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(os.Stdin).Decode(&resp); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for k, v := range resp.TimeSeries1min {
        fmt.Printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",
            resp.MetaData.Symbol, resp.MetaData.LastRefreshed, k,
            v.Open, v.High, v.Low, v.Close)
    }
}
```

While will output something like:

```
$ go run main.go < msft.json
MSFT    2018-05-25 10:53:00 2018-05-25 10:49:00 98.6292 98.6292 98.5700 98.5750
MSFT    2018-05-25 10:53:00 2018-05-25 10:40:00 98.8700 98.8701 98.7900 98.8300
MSFT    2018-05-25 10:53:00 2018-05-25 10:22:00 98.6460 98.6500 98.6000 98.6300
```

...

Comment: @MeronWA, just remember, the internet knows your API key now.